# Error while executing e2e test in kubernetes

Tags: testing, kubernetes

I am trying to run e2e test case of kubernetes but facing this issue .
 `../../cluster/../cluster/gce/util.sh: line 127: gcloud: command not found`
I am using this command

```
 go run hack/e2e.go -- -v --test
```

What should be the fix for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try prepending

```
KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=local KUBE_MASTER=local go run hack/e2e.go -- -v --test
```

The E2E tests are written to build up and tear down a cluster for you. The provider is used to do just that. there are providers e.g. for Gcloud and AWS. That is also the reason why you get the gcloud error. It tries to build a new cluster on GCloud and cannot find the CLI binary.

With the local provider this shouldn't happen.